# Microsoft Bot Framework works locally, but fails remotely

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, botconnector

I have this bot that is fairly complicated, but it works locally. But as soon as I publish it, it fails with the error:

> Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.

I have tried using Application Insights, but it isn't showing the error details.
The error always happens at the same point:

```
/// <summary>
/// Start our response
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current context</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{

    // Get our current step
    _groups = await _groupProvider.ListAsync();
    _group = _groups.First();

    // Post the question header
    await context.PostAsync(_group.Text);

    // Wait for the users response
    context.Wait(AskQuestion);
}

/// <summary>
/// When our message is recieved we execute this delegate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current context</param>
/// <param name="result">The result object</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task AskQuestion(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{

    // Get our question and answers
    var question = this._group.Questions[_currentQuestion];
    var questionText = question.Text;
    var answers = question.Answers.Select(m => m.Text).ToList();
    var answerCount = question.Answers.Count;

    // Create our options
    var options = new PromptOptions<string>(questionText, options: answers);

    // Ask our question
    Choice<string>(context, GetAnswer, options);
}

/// <summary>
/// Get our answer and decide what to do next
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current context</param>
/// <param name="result">The answer text</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task GetAnswer(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{

    // Get our quest
    var questions = _group.Questions;
    var length = questions.Count;
    var question = _group.Questions[_currentQuestion];
    var selectedAnswer = await result;

    // Assign our answer to our question
    foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
        if (answer.Text == selectedAnswer)
            question.Answer = answer;

    // If we have an answer, filter the products
    if (question.Answer != null)
        _productProvider.Score(await GetCurrentProducts(), _groups);

    // Increase our index
    _currentQuestion++;

    // If our current index is greater or equal than the length of the questions
    if (_currentQuestion == length)
    {

        // Create our dialog
        var dialog = _dialogFactory.CreateSecondStepDialog(_dialogFactory, _groupProvider, _questionProvider, _productProvider, await GetCurrentProducts());

        // Otherwise, got to the next step
        await context.Forward(dialog, ResumeAfter, new Activity { }, CancellationToken.None);
        return;
    }

    // Ask our next question
    await AskQuestion(context, null);
}
```

So when this **dialog** starts, it posts the question introduction to the client.
I then invoke **context.Wait** and ask the question. The question is a choice. I believe that this is where the issue is, because it always throws that message as soon as the question appears.

Can anyone spot anything glaringly obvious with the code?

Comment: What version of the BotBuilder nuget r u running?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have cited, is given when your bot throws a 500.  Looking at your code, my guess is that you have a null ref exception.  In the section under "// Get our question and answers", try checking that *group.Questions* isn't null and that *_currentQuestion* is a valid index into that array.